I found out years later 4 years ago exactly, 5 of my husbands patents he was only assignee and only inventor
I was asked to sign over two of my late husband's 52 patents just after he passed away, at the time I thought he only had those two.  Years later almost four years ago I found he actually has 52 patents.  I kept looking into it and found there were 5 of the utility patents he was only assignee and only inventor, now I see online they are saying I Gwendolyn Meagher assigned the other 5 patents over to the company, this is not true. I haven't never signed any other but the previous 2 utility patents. I wish I could gt help with this and if I am owed infringement I can get it, I think they know I have no money for a lawyer. The company has somehow made sure I did not get my late husbands retirement benefits. I don't have knowledge of what to do or how to go about, I am a Black woman my husband was cacausion, I cannot help but wonder if something was done so that his family would get his estate. I cannot find where the estate was probated here in the county we lived in, If you have advice for me please email me, meaghergwendolyn66@gmail.com or text 281-309-7929.  Thank you so much, Gwendolyn Meagher

I’m sorry to say there is little we can help with. If you had even stated your husband’s name we could have looked into whether any of the patents are still unexpired. You probably need a lawyer and you may be able to get one to help on a contingency basis.

So sorry I didn't see your comment,remember me Gwendolyn Meagher, my Husband's name is Thomas Bruce Meagher see(patent guru) Google, I am normally on Google, you know what I think

According to Google Patents your husband Thomas Bruce Meagher had 26 granted patents. Google Patents lists 52 documents with him listed as inventor, but 26 of those are applications. I also looked him up on Lens.org which I think is often better than Google Patents. There he is listed as an inventor on 31 patents, 30 of which are still active. Only on six he is listed as the Applicant.
Now the applicant is not necessarily the owner of a patent. I checked and on all six of them the assignee is either Ics Triplex Technology Limited, Rockwell Automation Limited or both. This isn't surprising. When you work for company (especially larger companies) they own your work product. I have over 100 patents and I'm the assignee of none of them. Typically when a patent is applied for the company asks you to assign them ownership. This is mere formality as the employment agreement already gives the company ownership. If you actually look at the originally published PDFs of those six patents you'll see that Rockwell or ICS or both are right there listed as the assignee on the front page. Possibly the source of your confusion is that you may have been looking at applications where the assignee isn't necessarily listed.
Now, I am not a patent lawyer. From what I see, your husband never owned any of his patents. However, I could be wrong. If you believe you've been wronged, then I think your only option is to consult with a lawyer.
